# Why the output of function `fork` contains unexpected thing?

Tags: c, unix, fork

I am writing a piece of C code using function `fork()`, and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d", pid);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
129660%
```

I wonder where this `%` comes from, and if I write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d\n", pid);
    return 0;
}
```

then the output becomes:

```
12946
0
```

This fits my expectation. Can anyone tell me how `%` comes from?

Comment: Probably the first symbol of your shell prompt?

Comment: It's presumably the prompt from your terminal, add a newline after your print

Comment: It's from your shell, denoting that there is no trailing newline in the output

Comment: Thanks, I see. How silly am I!

Comment: If you change a string in `printf` and the result changes, why do you assume, `fork` could be involved?